# Detecting Oracle database transient faults and reducing retries across multiple Runnables

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, jdbc, exception

I have a collection of `JobRequest` objects that are wrapped in `Worker` objects:

```
public class Worker implements Runnable {
    private final ProcExecutor executor;
    private final JobRequest request;

    public Worker(ProcExecutor executor, JobRequest request) {
        this.executor = executor;
        this.request = request;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // this might throw an SQLException
        executor.execute(request);
    }
}
```

These are executed against a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with 8 core threads and an unbounded task queue.

The `ProcExecutor` opens an [OracleConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html), creates a [CallableStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html) from the `OracleConnection` and `JobRequest`, executes the `CallableStatement`, and closes everything.  Creating the connection, creating the statement, and executing the statement can all throw `SQLExceptions`.

The problem I'm having is that I want the `Worker` to retry the job execution (using an [ExponentialBackoffPolicy](http://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/1.1.2.RELEASE/apidocs/) from [Spring-Retry](http://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/1.1.2.RELEASE/apidocs/) with an initial period of 500ms, a final period of 30,000ms, and unlimited retries - the user can intervene and cancel the retry loop if they wish) if the exception is transient, and to log the exception and exit the `Worker` if the exception is fatal.  At present I'm using [pingDatabase](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html#pingDatabase__) to test for transient faults:

```
public class DatabasePingException extends SQLException {
    public DatabasePingException(SQLException cause) {
        super("Ping Exception", cause);
    }
}

public class ProcExecutor {
    public void execute(JobRequest request) throws SQLException {
        try(OracleConnection connection = // create connection) {
            try {
                if (oracleConnection.pingDatabase() != OracleConnection.DATABASE_OK) {
                    throw new SQLException("Invalid database connection");
                }
            } catch(SQLException e) {
                throw new DatabasePingException(e);
            }
            // create and execute CallableStatement
        }
    }
}
```

The `Worker` then retries on a `DatabasePingException` and otherwise logs the exception and exits on a general `SQLException`.

(At least) two problems:

1. Is there a better way of distinguishing between transient and non-transient faults?  I realize that `SQLException` has subclasses for [transient](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLTransientException.html) and [non-transient](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLNonTransientException.html) faults, but I'm unclear as to how I should treat subclasses such as [SQLRecoverableException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLRecoverableException.html), e.g. retry a fixed number of times with a fixed retry period or else treat as a non-transient fault, or whether [SQLWarning](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLWarning.html) even needs to be retried at all.
2. If all of the `Workers` are encountering transient faults then ideally I'd like to pause all but one of them until the problem clears up.  The only solutions I've come up with involve breaking `Worker` encapsulation with something like a shared `Semaphore`, or else something heavyweight with the `ThreadPoolExecutor` like calling `shutDownNow()` and restarting all of the `Workers` that were cancelled or never executed.  I suspect that all of this is overkill if I'm using exponential backoff as even with eight threads this will only that each thread is pinging the database once every thirty seconds once the backoff reaches its maximum, but if there's a simple solution then I ought to employ it.